# from backports import csv ImportError: cannot import name csv

Tags: python-2.7, spacy, backport

I am using a NLP tool which is built on [Python Spacy](https://spacy.io/). This tool is called [textacy](https://github.com/chartbeat-labs/textacy). I installed Spacy, textacy and downloaded Spacy data for english. All on my **Python2.7**

Now, when I am trying to use textacy to extract noun chunks:

```
NNs = textacy.extract.noun_chunks(doc2, drop_determiners=True, min_freq=1)
for nn in NNs:
    print(nn)
```

It keeps showing me this

```
import textacy
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/textacy-0.3.2-py2.7.egg/textacy/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from textacy import corpora
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/textacy-0.3.2-py2.7.egg/textacy/corpora/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .wiki_reader import WikiReader
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/textacy-0.3.2-py2.7.egg/textacy/corpora/wiki_reader.py", line 32, in <module>
from textacy.compat import PY2, bytes_to_unicode, unicode_type
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/textacy-0.3.2-py2.7.egg/textacy/compat.py", line 6, in <module>
from backports import csv
ImportError: cannot import name csv
```

Therefore I have tried to install `backports.csv`. I tried from version 1.0 to the newest version 1.0.3, it kept retuning me this same error....

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: you could have another module named backports.  Or you are installing this one in the wrong place?  Can you do a successful `from backports import csv
` from the python prompt?

Comment: I cannot, it shows import error. And just chekced all the libraries in sitepackage, I have these 2: `backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.5.0.1-py2.7.egg` and `backports_abc-0.4-py2.7.egg`. Is this the reason? If so, do you know what should I do now?

Comment: One way to test for conflicts in packages/modules it to rename the directories in question, and/or test/install them again to see what works.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install python-dev
reinstall backports.csv

Comment: You should add an explanation for your code. And welcome to SO!